# In Windows, how can I launch cygwin shells n times and then resize their windows?

Tags: windows, cygwin

My hope is to one-click a shortcut, and get a grid of cygwin shells laid out before me, filling up my whole screen.

Any idea where I should start looking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rxvt has a geometry option:

> rxvt --geometry 100x10+500+200

gives you a rxvt window 100 columns wide, 10 rows tall, at (upper-left) pixel location 500x, 200y.

To invoke from a batch file so that in the background (like "&" on unix), use start:

> start C:\cygwin\bin\rxvt

To fill a 2560x1600 monitor with a grid of 4 cygwin rxvt windows, you'd make a batch file like this:

> start C:\cygwin\bin\rxvt --geometry 179x65+0+0 -sl 1500 -fn "Lucida Console-12" -bg black -fg grey -sr -e /usr/bin/bash --login -i
>    start C:\cygwin\bin\rxvt --geometry 179x65+1280+0 -sl 1500 -fn "Lucida Console-12" -bg black -fg grey -sr -e /usr/bin/bash --login -i
>    start C:\cygwin\bin\rxvt --geometry 179x65+0+800 -sl 1500 -fn "Lucida Console-12" -bg black -fg grey -sr -e /usr/bin/bash --login -i
>    start C:\cygwin\bin\rxvt --geometry 179x65+1280+800 -sl 1500 -fn "Lucida Console-12" -bg black -fg grey -sr -e /usr/bin/bash --login -i

If you aren't already using rxvt, I *highly* recommend it (or any other terminal that is better than a DOS box).

Comment: That is super awesome.  I was already using rxvt, didn't know about this option.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:  `.pif` files and a batch file...  Long answer: Write some code to create the processes and locate the windows where you want them.

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar with a small batch file called "openx.bat" that just contains:

```
@c:\cygwin\bin\run -p /usr/bin /bin/bash -c "ps | grep -q XWin && DISPLAY=:0 . ~/.startxwinrc || startxwin.exe &"
```

This will check to see if I have an active XWin server running, and start one if I don't.  If I do, it just reloads my .startxwinrc file, which contains the following lines:

```
#!/bin/sh

bash -l -c 'xterm -geometry 144x48+25+50' &
bash -l -c 'xterm -geometry 144x48+715+520' &
bash -l -c 'xterm -geometry 144x48+1615+520' &
bash -l -c 'xterm -geometry 144x48+2300+50' &
```

This can (and should) be modified to suit your own preferences - I'm using this on a dual monitor system, and this puts shell windows two on a screen in locations I find to be convenient.

The last step is I created a desktop shortcut to launch openx.bat, and I used the icon from XWin.exe as the icon for the shortcut.  If you're on Vista, you can drag the shortcut to your "quick launch" bar, too.